# Error when iterating through FormGroup in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form in my Angular 6 application which is giving me errors when trying to dynamically create the form controls:

In this case, questionValues is a FormGroup with multiple controls:

**report-create.ts** has the following on Init:

```
this.reportForm = this.fb.group({
  // there are other parts to this form which I'm leaving out
  questionValues: this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions)
});
```

toFormGroup is bascially the same code out of https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form:

```
toFormGroup(questions: ReportQuestionBase<any>[]) {
  const group: any = {};

  questions.forEach(question => {
    group[question.key] = question.required ? new FormControl(question.value || '', Validators.required)
      : new FormControl(question.value || '');
  });
  return new FormGroup(group);
}
```

And this is my html:

```
<form [formGroup]="reportForm" *ngIf="reportForm">
  // once again leaving out the other items
  <app-report-questions [questionValues]="reportForm.controls.questionValues"></app-report-questions>
</form>
```

**report-questions.ts** just has an Input():

```
@Input() questionValues: FormGroup;
```

With the following html:

```
<div [formGroup]="questionValues">
  <div *ngFor="let question of questionValues.controls" class="form-row">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput formControlName="question">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives the error "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: ngfor iterates through objects in array, can you check whats the value of questionValues.controls

Comment: It’s a questionValues is a formGroup so questionValues.controls are all the controls in my form

Comment: have you try < app-report-questions [questionValues]="reportForm.get('questionValues') ">?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

questionValues.controls is a formGroup object, it's not a formArray. You cannot use *ngFor. You can try keyValue pipe or Object.keys() method.

```
<div [formGroup]="questionValues">
  <div *ngFor="let questionkey of Object.keys(questionValues.controls)" class="form-row">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput formControlName="questionValues.controls[questionkey]">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that’s helpful - should I be iterating over wuestionValues.controls or questionValues by itself?